# Display user details with their average rating in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

In my case, I have two table like **users table and rating table**.

In **user table**, I'm storing user's personal details like **name, email** etc,

In **rating table**, I'm storing **user_id and rating(rating will be in numbers like 1,2,3,4 and 5)**

I have created relationship two tables
here is the relation

```
//User Model
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
}

//Rating model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Consultant::class);
}
```

I can able to display get data with eager loading

```
 $data = User::with('ratings')->get();
```

The Response I'll get from  eager load is

```
 [
 {
 "id": 1,
 "cunsultant_name": "Quincy Jerde",
 "contact_number": "882-904-3379",
    "ratings": [
    {

        "user_id": 1,
        "rating_for_user": 3

    },
    {

        "user_id": 1,
        "rating_for_user": 5
    },
    {

        "user_id": 2,
        "rating_for_user": 3
    }
    ]
    },
    {
   "user_name": "Alene Dicki",
   "contact_number": "247.604.8170",
        "ratings": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 3,
                "rating_for_user": 3
            }
    ]
 }
]
```

So how can I get an average rating for every user with eager loading?

Comment: Have you tried with `join` and `avg` funtion ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried @SagarGautam, User details will not display come if user has no rating when I use join and avg.

Answer (score 14):

To get the average rating with eager loading you can do

```
$user->ratings()->avg('rating_for_user');
```

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it, this is how you'd do it in Laravel.

Comment: hello @giollianosulit from where you getting $user variable.

Comment: @justin I think you mean me. The $user was variable is just example. If data contains multiple users than you have to iterate the data with an foreach e.g.

Comment: You can use that on the `$data` variable, after you've set the `User::with('ratings')->get();`. But you'd need to first loop through the `$data` then you can do `$data->ratings()->avg('rating_for_user');`

Comment: @giollianosulit It shows only first user rating after loop through

Comment: To get all the user ratings you need to call it within the loop and echo it out there.

Comment: Yes I did same $data = User::with(''ratings');  foreach($data as $d) { $ratings = $data->ratings()->avg('rating_for_user'); return $rating;}

Answer (score 1):

This will always append average_rating field in product. I use morph relation for ratings but you can use any relation appropriate for your situation.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded  = [];

    protected $appends = ['average_rating'];


    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Rating::class, 'rateable');
    }

    public function getAverageRatingAttribute()
    {
        return $this->ratings()->average('value');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
$data = User::with('ratings')
->join('Rating table','user.id','=','Rating table.user_id')
->select('user.*',DB::raw('avg(rating_for_user)'))
->get();
```

Modify the code as per your need.

I hope it help.

Comment: Thanks brother...@sagar

Comment: This query works only when the user has at least one rating If the user has no rating user details won't come.

Comment: May be, or may not be. may be it fetches only user data while there is no rating. Sorry i am not sure.

Comment: I have tried you It fetches user who has ratings, and also group by is missing in the query. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get ratings of multiple users you can do like this.

```
  $users = User::where('type', 'instructor')->get();
  foreach ($users as $user) {
      $user['ratings'] = $user->ratings()->avg('rate');
  }
  return $users;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get avg rating like this,

```
$product=Products::where('id',$productid);
$data=$product->with('ratings')->get();
foreach($data as $d) {
   return $d->ratings->avg('rating'); 
}
```

I have added code for product avg rating where two model like below:

**Product Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class Products extends Model {

protected $table = "products";
public $timestamps = false;

public function ratings()
{
 return $this->hasMany("App\Model\Reviews","p_id");
}
}
```

**Review Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reviews extends Model
{
protected $table = "product_reviews";
public $timestamps = false;

//Rating model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Products");
}
}
```